# Can you draw weapon while standing up from prone?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, actions

If you have a +1 BAB, you can draw your weapon during a “regular move.” Does standing up from prone count as a regular move? Or do they mean moving distance like 30 ft.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By “regular move” they are referring to the move action [Move](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#move): using a move action to move. Moving from some other action, or using your move action to do something else, don’t qualify.

Unfortunately, the rules don’t really come out and *explain that* anywhere. Context and consensus is all that can really be offered. The rules do this quite a lot with words like *regular*, *normal*, or *usual*, and they’re frequent sources of confusion.